# All the process logs from container

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

I have a container, it starts  with shell `script.sh` such as:

```
 FROM bash:4.4

 COPY script.sh /
 COPY process.sh /

 CMD ["bash", "/script.sh"]
```

Here is `script.sh`:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 sh process.sh &

 for i in {1..10000}
 do
     sleep 1
   echo "Looping ... number $i"
 done
```

It starts another process by running `process.sh` script.

Here is the `process.sh` script:

```
 #!/bin/sh
for i in {1..10}
 do
   sleep 1
   echo "I am from child process ... number $i"
 done
```

Now I want to see all the stdout message. If I go to the directory like `/var/lib/docker/containers/container_sha`:
I see something like below:

```
I am from child process ... number {1..10}
Looping ... number 1
Looping ... number 2
Looping ... number 3
Looping ... number 4
Looping ... number 5
Looping ... number 6
.....
```

It is obvious that, I see only the `script.sh` output but not `process.sh`

Why is that? And how can i get all the logs?

Note: `docker logs containerName` does the same.

Comment: `It is obvious that, I see only the script.sh output but not process.sh` where do you think the line `I am from child process ... number {1..10}` comes from?

Comment: I found the issue with the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`{1..10}` is bash syntax, and does not expand to anything in `sh`. So the loop runs once, with the word `{1..10}` (literally).

You can run `process.sh` with `bash` instead of `sh`

Or if you want/need `sh`, you could either:

Use a counter:

```
while c=$((c+1)); [ "$c" -le 10 ]; do
```

Use a program like `seq` (not POSIX):

```
for i in $(seq 10); do
```

Iterate arguments passed from bash like:

```
sh process.sh {1..10} &
```

and in `process.sh`:

```
for i do
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. If i ran `./process.sh &` instead of `sh process.sh &`, it does the print as expected. I mean start printing the line such as ```I am from child process ... number 1 \n I am from child process ... number2``` Why does it happen? I would appreciate your answer. Thanks

Comment: @OmarFaroqueAnik Backrounded processes are connected to the same tty and will print output at the same time as the foreground process, to the same tty (unless redirected). Make sure you use `#!/bin/bash` shebang in `process.sh`.